# adding divs dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want the user should be able to add 5 divs dynamically on click of plus icon after that alert should come only 5 divs can be added but odd numbers are not coming.

```js
function addvv() {
  var numItems = $('div.box').length;
  if (numItems <= 5) {
    $('.box').clone().appendTo('.container');
    var x = document.getElementById("removediv");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    }
  } else {
    alert('only 5 can be added');
  }
}

function removediv() {
  $(".box").remove();
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="box">

    <div style="background-color:blue;height: 26px;border-radius: 14px;">

      //this is the button to add divs dynamically

      <i class="fas fa-plus" id="adddiv" onclick="addvv()" style="color: red;float: right;margin-right: 15px;margin-top: 2px;font-size: 18px;"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-trash" id="removediv" onclick="removediv()" style="color: red;float: right;margin-right: 15px;margin-top: 2px;font-size: 18px;display:none"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="background-color:lightgray;height:100px;border-radius: 23px;">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:10px">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label>Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label>Salary:</label>
          <input type="text" id="salary" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please suggest some function so i can add odd number of divs also.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several issues with your code. First, your conditional `numLength <= 5` allows running `clone()` when `numLength == 5` which allows a total of 6 clones, not the 5 you intend. Second, `$('.box').clone()` will clone all elements that match the selector `.box`. This means on first click it will clone one, on second it will clone two, etc.

I've fixed your code so that it will clone just one, display `#removediv` on all but the first `.box`, and remove the `.box` for which `#removediv` is clicked. Also, ids should be unique for the whole document so really you should be using classes.

```js
function addvv() {
    var numItems = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
    if (numItems.length < 5) {
        $('.box').first().clone().appendTo('.container');
        $('.box').not(':first').find('#removediv').css('display', 'block');
    }
    else {
        alert('only 5 can be added');
    }
}

function removediv(e) {
    $(e).closest('.box').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div  style="background-color:blue;height: 26px;border-radius: 14px;">
            <!-- //this is the button to add divs dynamically -->
            <i class="fas fa-plus" id="adddiv" onclick="addvv()" style="color: red;float: right;margin-right: 15px;margin-top: 2px;font-size: 18px;">+</i>
            <i class="fa fa-trash" id="removediv" onclick="removediv(this)" style="color: red;float: right;margin-right: 15px;margin-top: 2px;font-size: 18px;display:none">-</i>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="background-color:lightgray;height:100px;border-radius: 23px;">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:10px">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Salary:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="salary" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```